# Compress a tar.gz (lamp stack related)

Tags: linux, wordpress, lamp

I backed up a wordpress install that I'm working on. It's around 65Gig. Is there a way to compress a tar.gz file to something even smaller? The reason it's so big is that it has ton of videos in the source code.

Here is the ls -lh

```
-rw-------  1 odyssey odyssey  65G Feb 29 14:00 backup-2.29.2016_12-49-50_odyssey.tar.gz
```

Comment: Not really a question that falls into the remit of this site, [su] is probably a better place to ask. Flag for a mod to migrate.

Comment: I agree. I didn't notice the difference.

Comment: most current video formats are already compressing the stream quite efficiently, just like png or jpg do images, and the likelihood of getting a worthwhile squeeze out of that is minimal.  Applying any further compression to the existing compressed tar-ball of compressed images is not likely to do much, keeping CPU and I/O system busy for a long time aside. :}